# Passing variables from controller to mail class - Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, variables, controller

I'm trying to pass data from my controller to mail class but it won't work for some reasons.

Problem should be somewhere in variable passing but I don't have any error messages.

Controller code:

```
$send_data = [  
    "name" => $product->name,  
    "quantity" => $item->quantity,  
    "price" => $final_price  
];  

\Mail::to($email)->send(new OrderMail($send_data));
```

Mail class:

```
class OrderMail extends Mailable  
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $subject = "Úspešná objednávka";
public $send_data;

public function __construct($send_data)
{
    $this->send_data = $send_data;
}

public function build()
{
 $send_data = $this->send_data; 
 return $this->markdown('emails.ordered');
}
```

I would like to access data in emails.ordered view

Comment: *it won't work* is not a good reason. What's not working exactly? Any error messages?

Comment: nope, I don't have any. I just can't access it in view because the variable is not passed there

Comment: Could you show your mailable view?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Can you show how you've tried to access those variables in the blade file?

Answer (score 2):

```
public function __construct($send_data)
{
    $this->send_data = $send_data;
}

$this->send_data      // this is a variable that you can use in view.
```

You can access through `$send_data` variable (that is defined in `__construct()`).

Answer (score 0):

After all I was just stupid and made typo in my markdown file, here's how my markdown should looked:

```
@component('mail::message')

<h1>Dobrý deň {{$buyer}}!</h1> 
<p>Vaša objednávka bola spracovaná úspešne.<p>
@component('mail::table')
| Produkt         | Počet ks.            | Cena               |
|:---------------:|:--------------------:|:------------------:|
@foreach($send_data as $item)
|{{$item["name"]}}| {{$item["quantity"]}}| {{$item["price"]}}€|
@endforeach
<p>V prípade osobného odberu si môžete vyzdvihnúť tovar na predajni s týmto 
klúčom: {{$next_id}}</p>
@endcomponent
@endcomponent
```